# How to parse output from sse.client in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, server-sent-events

I am new to Python and am trying to get my ahead around parsing SSE client code.  I am using the [SSE Client library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sseclient/0.0.3).  My code is very basic and follows the sample exactly.  Here it is:

```
from sseclient import SSEClient


devID = "xxx"
AToken = "xxx"

sparkURL = 'https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/' + devID + '/events/?access_token=' + AToken

messages = SSEClient(sparkURL)

for msg in messages:
    print(msg)
    print(type(msg))
```

The code runs without a problem and I see some blank lines and SSE data coming through.  Here is the sample output:

```
<class 'sseclient.Event'>
{"data":"0 days, 0:54:43","ttl":"60","published_at":"2015-04-09T22:43:52.084Z","coreid":"xxxx"}
<class 'sseclient.Event'>

<class 'sseclient.Event'>
{"data":"0 days, 0:55:3","ttl":"60","published_at":"2015-04-09T22:44:12.092Z","coreid":"xxx"}
<class 'sseclient.Event'>
```

The actual output above looks like a dictionary, but its type is "sseclient.Event".  I am trying to figure out how to parse the output so I can pull out one of the fields and nothing I have tried has worked.

Sorry if this is basic questions, but can someone provide some simple guidance on how I would either convert the entire output to a dictionary or perhaps just pull out one of the fields?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured this out.  In case anyone else experiences the same problem, here is how I got it to work.  The key was using msg.data and not just msg.  I then converted the out using the JSON library and am good to go.

```
messages = SSEClient(sparkURL)

for msg in messages:
    outputMsg = msg.data
    if type(outputMsg) is not str:
        outputJS = json.loads(outputMsg)
        FilterName = "data"
        #print( FilterName, outputJS[FilterName] )
        print(outputJS[FilterName])
```

Comment: i belive a "blank line" is often used be some sse server implemntations as a "keep-alive" type message.  thats said i think SSECLient should be filtering those out as they are "not a message".  sseclient is also upto 0.0.26 as of today so try updating your library versio if you still have issues.

Comment: msg.data is the key here. thanks!